# What is an Intuitive example of a Gauge Symmetry?

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, intuition

Can anyone give an intuitive example of what a gauge symmetry is? I am new to this concept and would like to understand it better!

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_gauge_theory#Electromagnetism)

Comment: A nice reference that ties together some of the answers below https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/torsors.html

Comment: You might find Maldacena’s economics analogy intuitive https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.6753

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Gauge Symmetry (not talking about large gauge transformations) refers to **mathematical** symmetries that are not physical but rather **redundancies** in our formulation.

It is a quite rich subject, but I will limit myself to intuitive answers.

Consider the magnetic field. We know that it is given by the **curl of a vector potential**

$$\mathbf{B = \nabla \times A}$$

Now notice that if you add a **curl-less** to **A**, the magnetic field stays the same, that is **the magnetic field is insensitive to curl-less terms**. This means that we have a symmetry where any transformation of A in the form of $\mathbf{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{A} + \nabla f$, where f is just a scalar function, leaves our **physics invariant**.

In physics it is efficient and effective to describe these symmetries by **gauge groups**, so groups that describe these redundancies, that is groups under whose action our model stays physically the same. The standard Model is described by $SU(3)\times SU(2) \times U(1) $, which all describe different aspects of the theory.

Gauge theory is a very rich subject that has shaped the way we approach physics.

Reading Recommendations:

[Large Gauge Transformation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72815/329086) (Gauge Transformations that cannot be thought of as redundancies.

[Yang Mills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory) (Wikipedia)

[Introduction to Gauge Theory for Beginners](https://williamsgj.people.cofc.edu/Gauge%20Theory.pdf)

Comment: To add to this point: note that we usually explicitly do experiments that "feel" the magnetic field, but we never seem to have direct access to the magnetic potential itself*; when we write things in terms of magnetic potential there is a redundancy in our description (this is the gauge symmetry). (*ignoring Aharanov-Bohm type subtelties)

Answer (score 10):

Another example of of a Gauge Symmetry can be found in the basic $V=mgh$.
Here you can have your "ground" anywhere you want. This freedom reflects the key idea in gauge theory.

Comment: Thank you. Can you think of this symmetry as an analogy with @MrDBrane’s answer?

Comment: It gets a bit messy sometimes because the gauge groups have different dimensions. The "gauge fields", which reflect the gauge freedom can be of different forms, so you can always exchange interpretations.

Comment: Yes. In the particular case of QED, the freedom to choose an electromagnetic gauge corresponds to the fact that you should come up with all the same object level predictions -- collisions of particles, for example -- no matter your path through spacetime, even if you accelerate.

Answer (score 3):

Take a potential that only depends on the distance of an object’s center from a center point. Then you can consider a rotation of your object. If this transformation acts locally, so the rotation for example is dependent o. You spacetime location, then you have a gauge symmetry and the rotations are gauge transformations.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

1. A toy model of a gauge theory is
   $$ Z ~\propto~\int \! dx ~dy~ e^{iS(x)}, \tag{71.8}$$
   cf. Ref. 1. The action $S(x)$ and the path integral $Z$ are invariant under a gauge transformation
   $$y\quad\longrightarrow\quad y^{\prime}~=~y+f(x).$$
   The $y$ variable is redundant/unphysical. See Ref. 1 for further details on how to gauge-fix the theory.
2. In more realistic [gauge theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory), it is more difficult (if not impossible) to cleanly separate physical and unphysical DOF, but the underlying idea is the same.

References:

1. M. Srednicki, *QFT, 2007;* chapter 71. A prepublication draft PDF file is available [here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/qft.html).